# Ffmpeg Piping output to pifm

Tags: ffmpeg, troubleshooting, pifm

I am trying to convert mp3 audio files on the fly with ffmpeg since pifm(a program to transmit over the FM band) only takes a specific file. I was told I could use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm -
```

But ffmpeg returns an error saying that I must select at least one output source. How can I fix this to recognize that it is supposed to pipe it to the **pifm** program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#pipe) said your syntax should be;

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 pipe:1 | sudo ./pifm -
```

`-` is common and `pipe:1` is not, but that's what it supports.